# Casting void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I've seen a lot of the following in older C code:

```
type_t *x = (type_t *) malloc(...);
```

What's the point of casting the pointer returned from `malloc()` since it's `void *`? Is it because older C compilers didn't support void pointers and `malloc()` used to return `char *` instead?

Comment: C allows this, whereas C++ does not.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean you should cast `void*` when programming in C.  C is not C++.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your own explanation is the right one. Pre-ANSI C ('K&R' C) did not have a `void *` type with implicit conversion. `char *` doubled as a pseudo `void *` type, but you needed the explicit conversion of a type cast.

In modern C the casting is frowned upon because it can suppress compiler warnings for a missing prototype of `malloc`. In C++, the casting is needed (but there you should be using `new` instead of `malloc` most of the time).

#### Update

My comments below that try to explain why the cast is required were a bit unclear, I'll try to explain it better here. You might think that even when `malloc` returns `char *`, the cast is not needed because it is similar to:

```
int  *a;
char *b = a;
```

But in this example a cast is also needed. The second line is a *constraint violation* for the simple assignment operator (C99 6.5.1.6.1). Both pointer operands need to be of compatible type. When you change this to:

```
int  *a;
char *b = (char *) a;
```

the constraint violation disappears (both operands now have type `char *`) and the result is well-defined (for converting to a char pointer). In the 'reverse situation':

```
char *c;
int  *d = (int *) c;
```

the same argument hold for the cast, but when `int *` has stricter alignment requirements than `char *`, the result is *implementation defined*.

Conclusion: In the pre-ANSI days the type cast was necessary because `malloc` returned `char *` and not casting results is a constraint violation for the '=' operator.

Comment: I also think this argument is the most plausible one. Yet even if malloc() returns char *, such a cast is technically not necessary because the type of the lvalue cannot be changed anyway.

Comment: @Blagovest K&R2 (p142) says the cast is necessary, but the errata list (http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) retracts this and adds: "On the other hand, pre-ANSI, the cast was necessary, and it is in C++ also."

Comment: My remark tried to explain that

char *c; int *x; x = c;

is technically OK apart from the warning you would get from the compiler.

Comment: I think your wrong there, because of alignment issues: From C99 6.3.2.3 (7): "A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the  pointed-to type, the behavior is undeﬁned."

Comment: Doesn't x = c; and x = (int *) c; produce absolutely the same machine code?

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: `x = c` isn't required to compile at all - it violates a "shall" clause in the standard.  It is legitimate for the compiler to reject it as an error rather than just issue a warning.

Comment: @schot: Thank you for the insightful explanation. I now understand that this is a violation against the language specifications, but I couldn't get the stuff about alignment issues since we are not talking about dereferencing pointers. On the machine level, doesn't char *, int *, void *, or any other pointer look exactly the same and have the same alignment?

Comment: I think I actually understood it... You mean that by casting the pointer the actual address can be "rounded" to match the alignment of the target type?

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is not compatibility with any dialect of C. The problem is **C++**. In C++, a void pointer cannot be automatically converted to any other pointer type. So, without an explicit cast, this code would not compile with a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware that malloc ever returned a char*.

But implicit casting from void* to type_t* (or any other type) hasn't always been allowed.
Hence, the need to explicitly cast to the proper type.

Comment: Prior to C89, malloc() returned `char *`.  The `void *` type was introduced with C89 precisely because of the need for a "generic" pointer type that could be implicitly converted to any other pointer type.  As of C89, there is no reason to explicitly cast the result of malloc().

Comment: I stand corrected.  I was never aware that malloc returned char* once upon a time.  Good to know.

Answer (score -3):

> What's the point of casting the pointer returned from malloc() since it's void *?

Quite the contrary. You *need* to cast a void pointer to an actual type before you can use it, because a `void *` signifies nothing about the data stored at that location.

Comment: I am not attempting to dereference a void pointer without casting it. The point here is that the lvalue is a typed pointer and you still have to cast the rvalue before assignment.

Comment: A `void*` will be automatically converted to the corresponding `type_t*` on assignment

Comment: Your argument only says why x (in the OP) must be type_t*, not why there must be a cast to assign the value there.

Comment: -1 for incorrect usage of the word "cast", which refers to a `(type)` operator in C. You do need a conversion before the pointer can be used, but it will happen implicitly.