# Changing a static array to a dynamic one with minimal changes?

Tags: c, malloc

I have a C code that creates an array of char pointers as the following:

```
char* arr[100];
```

I use each element in this array to point to some string that is being calculated by another function. So basically arr[0] would point to string1 and arr[1] to string2, etc.

This works just fine. However I'm now asked to be more flexible by having the user to specify the number of strings as a parameter.

How can I do this with minimal changes to my code? I understand that I need to use malloc. However I'm getting a lot of warnings in all of the assignment statements I had before. I changed the declaration of the array as the following:

```
char* arr = (char*)malloc(n * sizeof(char*)); //where n is provided by user
```

I thought that I only needed to change the declaration. Now all of the assignment statements are giving warnings ("assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"). The following is an example of an assignment statement:

```
arr[i] = str; //where str is defined as char* and is calculated by another function
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking to create an array of `char *`, you need a `char **arr`. Think of it as an array of `char *` -- if you had an array of `int`, you would have `int *`. Since you have an array of `char *s`, you need `char **`.

```
char** arr = malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: Please, remove the cast. In C, no cast is needed when converting a `void *` to another pointer.

Comment: Changed, though I wasn't sure if the OP was using a C or C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `arr` as a pointer to `char`: either a single string or, if you prefer, an array of `char`s.

To allocate an array of pointers, declare `arr` as

```
char **arr = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
```

By the way, remove the cast: it is [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3559656/238421) in C. See also [Question 7.7](http://c-faq.com/malloc/cast.html) in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you want to declare `arr` as as `char **` since you are pointing to an array of pointers. If you declare `arr` only as `char *` (not `char **` or `char *[]`) you only have one "string".

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that string is an array too (`char *`), so u will need array of pointers, which should look like this:

```
char** arr = (char**)malloc(n * sizeof(char*));
```