# realloc: invalid next size

Tags: c, file-io

This question is definitely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532425/read-line-from-file-without-knowing-the-line-length) and it's answer is what I based my function off of.

```
char *get_next_line(FILE *fp) {
char ch = 0;
int CUR_MAX = 4095;
char *buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * CUR_MAX); // allocate buffer.
char *temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * CUR_MAX); // allocate buffer.
int count = 0;
int length = 0;

while ((ch != '\n')) {
  if (ch == '\377') { return NULL; }
  if(count ==CUR_MAX) {
    CUR_MAX *= 2;
    count = 0;
    if ((temp = realloc(buffer, CUR_MAX)) != NULL) {
      buffer = temp;
      free(temp);
    }
  }
  ch = getc(fp);
  buffer[length] = ch;
  length++;
  count++;
}
```

For some reason, when reading in very large strings I'm faced with:
**glibc detected - realloc() invalid next size.**

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related, but you should never store the result of `realloc` in the original variable.  If the `realloc` fails and returns `NULL`, the original block of memory will be orphaned, creating a memory leak.  Instead, store `realloc`'s return value in a temporary variable, check it for `NULL`, and copy it to the original variable only if it's valid.

Comment: Is it possible CUR_MAX is overflowing (becoming negative)? On a side not, the result of realloc should be assign to a temp variable in case it returns null (with your approach you would lose your reference to the buffer in this situation).

Comment: Edited to store result of realloc in a temp var, then set to buffer, then freed temp. The issue goes away but a seg fault still occurs.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but _please_ clean up your code of extraneous whitespace, you have a ridiculous amount of trailing whitespace which makes viewing your code in a mobile browser unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're accessing memory outside of your malloced/realloced region.

Not setting `count = 0` inside your while look should fix this.

---

To try and elaborate...

When starting the formula:

```
count = 0
length = 0
CUR_MAX = 4095
```

These will increment until they reach 4095. Once we reach 4095, we will have:

```
count = 0
length = 4096
CUR_MAX = 8190
```

We will then increment until count is 8190. Shorly before then, we have:

```
count = 8100
length = 12196
CUR_MAX = 8190
```

Your array is only 8190 in length, but you're dereferencing `buffer[12196]`, which is an invalid index.

---

*Also, you probably want to handle the `else` case for when `temp == NULL`. This probably can be handled by an `assert` or a big old failure. And don't `free(temp)` inside your success side. That's freeing the memory you just attempted to allocate. And is causing your new segmentation fault.*

Answer (score 4):

When you:

```
free(temp);
```

`buffer` is also freed, since:

```
buffer = temp;
```

So later on you're trying to:

```
realloc(buffer, CUR_MAX)
```

which cannot work because `buffer` has been freed indirectly through `temp`. You cannot `realloc()` a freed pointer.

Comment: This is also correct, In the edit, the user introduced this bug as well...

Comment: You don't need to free() the old buffer when realloc() succeeds, so doing `free(buffer);` before `buffer = temp;` would also be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

`realloc(buffer, CUR_MAX))` returns pointer to void.

I believe the correct statement is `(char *)realloc(buffer, CUR_MAX))`

Comment: Nope, the cast is not necessary in C (unlike C++) due to implicit conversion of `void*`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559656/casting-void-pointers) for discussion.