# Data Structure in C with pointers: I want to store an array of information in each position

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, calloc

How can I define a data structure in C, where for each position I want to store: an int array of size M, an int array of size N and a double value? I tried the following with no success yet.

At the beginning of my code I defined my data structure (LOCOPT) as follows:

```
typedef struct LOCOPT
{
  int    *org;
  int    *des;
  double value;
} LOCOPT;

LOCOPT *locopt;
```

Then, I initialized the locopt using calloc as follows:

```
for( locopt_ctr=0 ; locopt_ctr<locopt_max ; locopt_ctr++ )
{
    locopt[locopt_ctr].org = (LOCOPT *) calloc(M, sizeof(LOCOPT));
    locopt[locopt_ctr].des = (LOCOPT *) calloc(N, sizeof(LOCOPT));
}
```

When I tried to use it in the code it did not work: I want to do this:

```
for( m=0 ; m<M ; m++ )
locopt[locopt_ctr].org[m] = origin[m]; // regardless of what origin[m] is.
```

I need to use calloc several times instead of once only and I don't know how to do that. I need to use the loop properly. Any ideas please?

Comment: You didn't init locopt and arrays, post the full init code.

Comment: intialize locopt array and then initialize org and des.

Comment: `locopy` is a pointer to ... nothing. Either declare it as a non-pointer or malloc some at least one `LOCOPT` struct for it.

Comment: @self What do you mean by init? The three coding parts are all what I have regarding this issue.

Comment: @user3276935 I suggest looking at some questions showing how to allocate memory for simple types.

Comment: @Wajahat, How do I do that?

Comment: @self, I know how to allocate memory for simple types. I did that before. I don't know how to handle this one though.

Comment: Find the total size of this data structure array which is I think locopt_max * (Size of one LOCOPT)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much at once. Let's break this down to some simpler pieces first:

1. You've declared `LOCOPT *locopt`. Before you can use locopt itself as a pointer (or in array syntax) to anything, you have to allocate memory for it, eg

   `locopt[locopt_ctr] = (LOCOPT *) calloc(1,sizeof(LOCOPT));`

But that's only part of the effort.

1. If you want to store a list of items in each instance of locopt, then you need to call calloc again *on the members of the newly allocated locopt instance* :

   `locopt[locopt_ctr].org = (int *) calloc(M, sizeof(int));`
   `locopt[locopt_ctr].des = (int *) calloc(N, sizeof(int));`

Bottom line - if you've got a pointer, you've got to allocate it eventually.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers made it work. At least for now the code is running and it seems to be working. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Careful, given the way `locopt` was defined, you are dereferencing a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your allocations, one is about the memory for the `locopt` array itself, and the other  is about how you allocate memory for `des` and `org` in each structure.

First, we don't see if you ever allocate memory for your locopt structure array. If that has `L` elements, you could do

```
locopt = calloc(L, sizeof(LOCOPT));
```

Then, you still need to allocate memory for the fields `org` and `des` in it like this (for each structure, as you do), but

```
locopt[locopt_ctr].org = calloc(M, sizeof(int));
```

and likewise for `des`. `LOCOPT` is the name of your structure, but the type of your arrays is `int`.

Comment: I tried, but I still have an error. "a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to a value of type "int *". Any idea please?

Comment: Is this C or C++? If this is C++, you need to cast as done in the answer by @DavidW. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3559772/1916766.